# Get user ip address in zend framework

Tags: php, zend-framework2

How can I get the client's IP address in Zend-framework 2? It'd be $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] in plain PHP, but maybe is smart Zend function?

Any ideas?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

The request object(s) in ZF2 has method named `getServer`. This method returns an object implementing `\Zend\Stdlib\ParametersInterface`. With this particular object you can get anything from the $_SERVER variable.

Here are two examples of how to use the method and object:

```
<?php 
    // Getting the entire params object
    $servParam = $request->getServer();
    $remoteAddr = $servParam->get('REMOTE_ADDR');

    // Getting specific variable
    $remoteAddr = $request->getServer('REMOTE_ADDR');
?>
```

Comment: The overhead produced by this approach is nothing but unnecessary. For a simple task like just getting the Remote-Address, using the `$_SERVER` array is simply better.

Comment: @Sam I cannot agree more on that with you. But the purpose of this site is to give answers people's questions. And that is what we do. We mention an advice as well and it is up to the one that ask the question to decide what to do.

Comment: True point contained, however I usually follow the principle that users don't know what they want and therefore should be guided into the right direction. IMO my answer was missing the mentioning of the `getServer()` as well as your answer is missing the mentioning of overhead - no hard feelings tho :)

Comment: None taken ;). My advice is missing because I didn't want to advise to not use it. In fact I would advise to do use it since the `\Zend\Stdlib\Parameters` is a value object and I always encourage using value objects instead of arrays. Easier to test, this particular one allows specifying default value... as a matter of fact I would use it in my controllers myself if I need to :)

Comment: I came here in hope that ZF2 would make sure the IP exists as apparently the parameter is different in IIS/Apache: LOCAL_ADDR, SERVER_ADDR etc

Comment: I'd advise the use of the Zend approach over $_SERVER as it gives greater flexibility for testing - it's far easier to inject a Zend request object than modify your global variables in unit tests.

Answer (score 32):

You can use the `Zend\Http\PhpEnvironment\RemoteAddress` class to get the client ip address.

```
$remote = new Zend\Http\PhpEnvironment\RemoteAddress;
echo $remote->getIpAddress();
```

See http://framework.zend.com/apidoc/2.1/classes/Zend.Http.PhpEnvironment.RemoteAddress.html.

**Note:**

To enable inspection of the header `HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR`, turn on `setUseProxy()`:

```
$remote->setUseProxy()->getIpAddress();
```

Comment: The overhead produced by this approach is nothing but unnecessary. For a simply task like just getting the Remote-Address, using the `$_SERVER` array is simply better.

Comment: This class doesn't just look at REMOTE_ADDR but optionally checks the proxy ip and optionally filters out trusted proxies as well. If your server config is such that you can't rely on remote_addr the "overhead" of one object is nothing compared to the gains.

Comment: It does look at REMOTE_ADDR, and the proxy check is disabled by default. But it is a nice feature to know.

Answer (score -13):

Big Secret:

```
$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']
```

Don't reinvent already easy stuff!

Comment: The problem with this is, that `$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']` is not always reliable. What if the user is behind a proxy, and the IP is shown by `HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR` header? Don't be so fast to condescend.

Comment: If you listen the user question maybe you never aswer that. :)

Comment: @rafaelphp If you check the date of this question, you'd never post a stupid comment like that either. The reason I am not deleting my answer is because the guy above you has a nice comment with many upvotes. Everyone is wrong at times - this was one of the few times i gave a bad answer. No shame admitting that, that's why it's not deleted.

Comment: Easy down man! it just a comment!